# Outputting Audio to the Built-In output device (Not the Default One)

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

I need to do some system-wide audio processing in my app.
I have installed Soundflower and selected it as my default output device in order to get the system audio. I know that Soundflower merely copies the mix buffer to a ThruBuffer and passes it to the apps so they can get it in their `AudioDeviceIOProc` callback.
What I don't understand is how to route the audio back to the Built-In output device after I've done the audio processing. I have the Soundflower device as the default, and it produces silence as I try to route the audio to the default output unit. Maybe what I need is to create a Multi-Output device in my program but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a multi-output device on osx - they're called "aggregate devices". You can do it manually in Audio MIDI Setup app and use that device in your app, or do it programmatically in your app.

If you do do it in app, example code seems to be rare. I cribbed the info I needed from [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20090329022112/http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=51).

**NB**  the post is very old, I had to go to the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org) to find it.

Comment: Here's a later Apple document about the subject: [Create an Aggregate Device to combine multiple audio devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202000).